# Unable to connect to mongodb server

Tags: c#, mongodb

Mongodb server is running with no specific configuration, just download it and launched it (bin/mongod.exe, database: test - windows 7 x64, host: localhost)

Then I created a .Net application:

```
var server = MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost");
var database = server.GetDatabase("test");

using (server.RequestStart(database)) // MongoConnectionException - Unable to connect to server
```

the server:

> server.RequestStart(databaseC:\Users\Gary
>   Benattar\Desktop\Utils\MongoDb\mongodb-win32-x86_64-1.0.0\mongodb-
>
> win32-x86_64-1.0.0\bin\mongod.exe --help for help and startup options
>
> Mon Aug 08 16:12:02 Mongo DB : starting : pid = 0 port = 27017 dbpath
>   = /data/db
>
> / master = 0 slave = 0  64-bit
>
> Mon Aug 08 16:12:02 db version v1.0.0, pdfile version 4.4
>
> Mon Aug 08 16:12:02 git version:
>   dabf2ce54614c6de9d728af445eec47f39dde19f
>
> Mon Aug 08 16:12:02 sys info: windows (6, 0, 6002, 2, 'Service Pack
>   2')
>
> Mon Aug 08 16:25:13 connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:4847 #7
>
> Mon Aug 08 16:25:13 end connection 127.0.0.1:4847

Dll:

using MongoDB.Bson;

using MongoDB.Driver;

I also try without any firewall - btw I added a rule inside for mongodb and also VSstudio 2010

What can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed mongodb-win32-x86_64-1.8.2 instead of mongodb-win32-x86_64-1.0.0 and then, I created a new data folder and started mongo (as a windows service)- It worked fine...

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the port

```
mongodb://localhost:27017
```

If this doesn't work you should check the log output for mongo and make sure you have a data directory set up correctly. I'm not sure where it defaults to but on my machine it's `c:\data\db`, and I don't remember changing the defaults. Try creating that directory and try  again.

Comment: Unable to connect to server. - :(

Comment: You could try 127.0.0.1:27017, might want to check your windows config and verify localhost didn't get changed to something else

Comment: Same error with var server = MongoDB.Driver.MongoServer.Create("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");